# Some java handler to get url.openStream() only when results are available

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, web-content

I am looking for a way to open many connections to websites in java.

My problem is that the server response times are really slow in many occasions. I therefore thought it would be a good idea to look for some java library that can handle opening many connections and that perhaps uses a handler when the connection/response is ready.

Is there something like (this is pseudo code!!)

```
getWebsiteContent(URL url) { //does not wait for the response
new AsynchronousConnection(url) {

    requestServedHandler(ConnectionObject) {
        InputStream is = ConnectionObject.getInputStream();

        //here I will process the content of the stream only when it is available
    }
} 
}
```

I would not mind a handler that gives me the raw HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a specialized library, but you can create your own multi-threaded solution. Write your retriever task as a [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) that returns the HTML then submit these callables with the appropriate URLs to an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). There are loads of code examples for this pattern on the net, but I could write you one if you ask.
A little more hint: This setup resembles to the quite common producer-consumer pattern. Your tasks could put the site contents into a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) and let the processor thread poll in periodically to look for ready data. Either poll with a timeout if you want more liveliness or without, but that would block until data is available.

Comment: I will start looking into this, thank you! :) I suspect your time is valuable so don't write any code unless you really feel like it.

Comment: How large do you think I should make the thread pool? I took 10 threads now. How should I think about this?

Comment: @user1443778 It depends on the number of tasks you'd like to run, the number of CPU-s, I/O frequency and so. Since establishing the connection blocks, I think there is no benefit in using more than `CPUCount+1` threads (of course you can submit over this limit, just those tasks will wait until there is no cpu). But without measurements it's hard to get a precise approximation.